# Constructing an Algorithm which takes as Input Two DAG's and Returns the Longest Path found in Both

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

> Construct and describe an efficient algorithm which takes as input two directed acyclic graphs (DAG's) and finds the longest path which occurs in both of them.

> If there are several, the algorithm should return one of the longest paths (it doesn't matter which one). In summary, given the graphs G = (V,E) and G' =(V',E'), find the longest possible sequence <v1,...,vk> where (v_i,v_{i+1}) is in E **and** E' for i = 1...k-1.

Any ideas? I can write the actual code myself, I just need help with building the idea behind the actual algorithm and finding a solution to the problem.

Im thinking I could use recursive DFS and some memoization: while keeping track of visited nodes; for each starting node and for each neighbour, calculating the distance to the neighbour + the distance from the neighbour to the goal. Then taking the max of these, memoizing it as the max from this node, and returning it.

Using this approach for both DAG's, the issue from here would be to identify which of these paths is the longest that occurs in both.

Would appreciate any ideas/help.

Comment: How about adding an input and output example?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I wasn't given any. It's a practise problem in my algorithms and data structures course.

Comment: But for the stack overflow community to accurately understand your question and expected solution, an example would be needed. For example, I don't understand what "longest path found in both" means. Should the values in the path be same in both DAGs? or just the length needs to be same based on some criteria? 

+ This is a practice problem. So, we are interested in what efforts have you taken and where are you stuck. That's how we learn.

Comment: Two graphs are a red herring. Discard edges that do not belong to both graphs, and work with one graph. Now you need to find a longest path in one graph, which is a well known easy problem (for DAGs).

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Thank you for your feedback, I added some more description now to hopefully make it more clear. I do have a section with some of my own thoughts on how to solve the problem.

Comment: You already have the solution. Starting from every vertex, figure out what is the longest common path. DFS+memoize. Return the max length. If you want the path as well, memoize the longest path as well. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni The problem I have is that there are two graphs, and I need the longest path which is in both graphs. Do you suggest doing what the person above said about removing edges which do not belong to both graphs, and then work with only one graph?

Comment: Added an answer with the 3 approaches. That is why I was asking you to take an example so that you get the clarity of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Starting from every vertex, figure out what is the longest common path. DFS+memoize. Return the max length. If you want the path as well, memoize the longest path as well.
2. Find the intersection of the DAGs and return the longest intersecting path. You can find [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-graphs/) code for intersection of graphs. Similarly, you can do for DAGs as well.

In approach 1, you don't need to store the intersecting parts of the DAG, just the max length is sufficient. So, it is memory efficient as compared to approach two.

[image]

In first approach, you find out length of maximum matching path (BCD here) and return the length.

In second approach, you'll store the matching parts (BCD here) and return the longest path length from it.

[image]

Approach 3:

@"n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m." mentions another approach in the comments where you delete the edges from one graph which are not present in another graph.

So, if you delete from graph 1 the edges which are not present in graph 2, you'll get the below:

[image]

In the above graph if you do the DFS, you'll get 3 as answer as BCD is the longest path.